# Removing unwanted characters from folder names

Tags: c#

I'm creating bunch of folders using a C# console application. An XML file is parsed for different nodes and based on the values the folders are created with the same name.

One of the XML node had the following value with some unknown special character in it (ASCII code 127)

[image: Foldername with special character]

There is a special character after Foldername. I tried using String.Trim() to trim the value but had no luck. I also tried to compare the character with the list of

```
System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
```

and remove it. But still no luck. How can I try to eliminate these characters before I create a folder name. The folder name will be always alpha numeric in my case.

Comment: I don't think so. The character which I'm getting is not illegal. But I just don't want it in the name because it does not make any sense.

Comment: The title of the question is somewhat misleading then

Comment: Tried my best to rename it :)

Answer (score 2):

If the folder name will "always be alpha numeric", then you can simply remove all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
var regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
fileName = regex.Replace(fileName, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the unwanted characters using Regular Expressions -

```
string validFolderName = Regex.Replace(folderName,"[^A-Za-z0-9 _]","");
```